# Drupal - 7 category/taxonomy with nodes in block

Tags: drupal-7, block, categorization

I am new in drupal 7 and I want to create one view blog in which I can list out taxonomy as category and in under that I want to display two articles and a read more link to that category.  Can any one explain in details how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a content type with a **Term reference field** for your category, it wil automatically create pages for each category with the articles tagged with that category listed within it.

If you want to have more control over these pages generated by the Taxonomy module, you can turn on the **Taxonomy Term** example view in de Views UI and add and remove the fields you want to display. The layout of these pages can be edited by creating a custom template file in you themes template folder for the file **page--taxonomy.tpl.php**.

There you could als create an additional block display (*I assume you mean block when you say blog*), and in the Page settings area, you can turn on de **More link**, and this will display a more link when more articles are available then you have set you pager to display (*i.e. Use pager - Display a specified number of items - Items per page = 2*). Make sure you change de setting from **For all displays** to **This block (override)** to not override the other displays.

This block you can place in any region on any page via the Blocks UI and is should do what you want.